# Check if CD/DVD is Finalized

Tags: windows-7, burning, dvd-burning, cd-burning

Is there a simple way to check if re-writable media has been finalized?  So far the only recommendations I can find suggest that I attempt to start another write session using the disc and if it fails assume it is finalized.

Comment: A disc-burning application, such as the free (and portable) InfraRecorder, will tell you the disc status, if Windows doesn't tell you. You don't need to attempt to burn anything.

Comment: @AFH - I'd like to do this through the OS if possible without having to install 3rd party SW.

Comment: I presumed you had already tried DVD->Properties from explorer. The reason third-party applications exist is because there are lots of things that Windows doesn't do. If you use the portable version, you won't have to install anything.

Comment: Third-party apps really are necessary here. Windows does a poor job of burning disks;  for instance, adding "desktop.ini", and not finalizing disks after burning, even if you select the "With a CD/DVD player (Mastered) option.

Answer (score 4):

Check the drive properties in File Explorer. If the Free Space shows as 0, then the disc is finalized. If the Free Space > 0, then the disc is not finalized.

Comment: People at our company have brought up an edge case where this may not work: where it rounds down to 0 Bytes available. Do you know a way that doesn't have this issue? (I'm trying to find the pedantic solution to tell them "this is what your policy should be")

Comment: @iAdjunct InfraRecorder can provide disc information on whether disc is incomplete/closed: https://superuser.com/a/1611322/243707

Answer (score 1):

InfraRecorder will show you information about the media in a drive.

```
Actions > Disc Information > (choose a removable drive)
```

Here is what you can expect to see:

## Blank

[image]

## Burned in Windows Explorer *(Windows 7, not finalized)*

[image]

## Burned in InfraRecorder *(Session-At-Once, Closed)*

[image]